# Force exerted by water flowing in a pipe bent into a circular arc

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, drag, viscosity

my school teacher told me that when water flows in a pipe, it exerts a force equal to $ρAv^2$ where $ρ$ is density, $A$ area and $v$ velocity. he further said that when the liquid enters the pipe, the direction of force is along velocity and when it leaves, the direction of force is opposite to velocity. This direction of force is what i don't understand, while entering why is it along velocity and while exiting, why is it opposite to velocity? **NOTE: I AM IN HIGH SCHOOL**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher is confused.  He hasn't even specified what exertes the force on what.  The proper momentum balance on the fluid in the pipe is $$\vec{F}=[\rho v A\vec{v}]_{out}-[\rho v A\vec{v}]_{in}$$where $\vec{v}$ is the velocity vector, $v$ is the magnitude of the velocity vector $\vec{v}$, $\vec{F}$ is the force exerted by the pipe on the fluid, $[\rho v A\vec{v}]_{out}$ represents the rate at which momentum flows out of the pipe and $[\rho v A\vec{v}]_{in}$ represents the rate at which momentum flows out of the pipe.  The equations says that the rate of change of fluid momentum is equal to the force exerted on the fluid.

The force exerted by the fluid on the pipe is, by Newton's 3rd law, $-\vec{F}$.

Comment: i dont get it, if we use this concept you explained, then what will be the net force on the pipe which i  have mentioned in the question. i am quite bad at physics, so if you could help me, i would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The velocity vector at the inlet is $$\vec{v}_{in}=\frac{-\hat{x}+\hat{y}}{\sqrt{2}}v$$where $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ are the unit vectors in the x and y directions, respectively.  The velocity vector at the outlet is $$\vec{v}_{out}=\frac{-\hat{x}-\hat{y}}{\sqrt{2}}v$$So, from the equation I wrote in my first Answer $$\vec{F}=\rho v^2 A\frac{-\hat{x}-\hat{y}}{\sqrt{2}}-\rho v^2 A\frac{-\hat{x}+\hat{y}}{\sqrt{2}}=-\sqrt{2}\rho v^2 A\hat{y}$$This is the force that the pipe exerts on the liquid.  The force that the liquid exerts on the pipe is $$+\sqrt{2}\rho v^2 A\hat{y}$$

Answer (score -2):

I think the force exerted on the pipe must be $\rho A v^2$ *per radian*. You can see this by calculating the force on a small length of pipe with length $ds = r d\theta$, and then integrating this around the angle covered by the whole pipe.

As for the direction of the force, it is everywhere perpendicular to the pipe. If there were any component of the force parallel to the pipe, then the pipe would exert an equal and opposite force on the water by Newton's third law, which would change the velocity $v$ of the water. But if we assume $v$ is constant along the length of the pipe then this cannot be true.

There are two important qualifications to this. First, I am assuming that the pipe is horizontal. Second, this only applies if there is no friction between the pipe and the water.